# Hibernate: En relación ManyToOne no me permiten enlazar objetos si no coinciden sus claves primarias

Tags: eclipse, hibernate

Veran, tengo 2 tablas.
Una es Seguro:

```
package es.makigas.hibernate.modelo;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;

public class Seguro implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

int id;
String nif;
String nombre;
String ape1;
String ape2;
int edad;
int numHijos;
LocalDate fechaCreacion;

List<AsistenciaMedica> asistenciasmedicas;

public Seguro() {}

public Seguro(int id, String nif, String nombre, String ape1, String ape2, int edad, int numHijos, LocalDate fechaCreacion){
    this.id = id;
    this.nif = nif;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.ape1 = ape1;
    this.ape2 = ape2;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.numHijos = numHijos;
    this.fechaCreacion = fechaCreacion;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNif() {
    return nif;
}

public void setNif(String nif) {
    this.nif = nif;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getApe1() {
    return ape1;
}

public void setApe1(String ape1) {
    this.ape1 = ape1;
}

public String getApe2() {
    return ape2;
}

public void setApe2(String ape2) {
    this.ape2 = ape2;
}

public int getEdad() {
    return edad;
}

public void setEdad(int edad) {
    this.edad = edad;
}

public int getNumHijos() {
    return numHijos;
}

public void setNumHijos(int numHijos) {
    this.numHijos = numHijos;
}

public LocalDate getFechaCreacion() {
    return fechaCreacion;
}

public void setFechaCreacion(LocalDate fechaCreacion) {
    this.fechaCreacion = fechaCreacion;
}

public List<AsistenciaMedica> getAsistenciasmedicas() {
    return asistenciasmedicas;
}

public void setAsistenciasmedicas(List<AsistenciaMedica> asistenciasmedicas) {
    this.asistenciasmedicas = asistenciasmedicas;
}
}
```

La otra es AsistenciaMedica:

```
package es.makigas.hibernate.modelo;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class AsistenciaMedica implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    int idAsistenciaMedica;
    Seguro seguro;
    String breveDescripcion;
    String lugar;

    public AsistenciaMedica(){}

    public AsistenciaMedica(int idAsistenciaMedica, Seguro seguro, String breveDescripcion, String lugar){
        this.idAsistenciaMedica = idAsistenciaMedica;
        this.seguro = seguro;
        this.breveDescripcion = breveDescripcion;
        this.lugar = lugar;
    }

    public int getIdAsistenciaMedica() {
        return idAsistenciaMedica;
    }

    public void setIdAsistenciaMedica(int idAsistenciaMedica) {
        this.idAsistenciaMedica = idAsistenciaMedica;
    }

    public Seguro getSeguro() {
        return seguro;
    }

    public void setSeguro(Seguro seguro) {
        this.seguro = seguro;
    }

    public String getBreveDescripcion() {
        return breveDescripcion;
    }

    public void setBreveDescripcion(String breveDescripcion) {
        this.breveDescripcion = breveDescripcion;
    }

    public String getLugar() {
        return lugar;
    }

    public void setLugar(String lugar) {
        this.lugar = lugar;
    }
}
```

Cada AsistenciaMedica se asigna a un unico Seguro, pero un Seguro puede tener varias asistencias.

Fichero hbm de Seguro:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="es.makigas.hibernate.modelo.Seguro" table="Seguro" >
        <id column="Id" name="id" type="integer"/>
        <property name="nif" />
        <property name="nombre" />
        <property name="ape1" />
        <property name="ape2" />
        <property name="edad" />
        <property name="numHijos" />
        <property name="fechaCreacion" />

        <list name="asistenciasmedicas"  cascade="all" inverse="false"  >
            <key>
                <column name="idAsistenciaMedica"  />
            </key>
                <list-index>
                    <column name="Idx"  />
                </list-index>
            <one-to-many class="es.makigas.hibernate.modelo.AsistenciaMedica" />
        </list>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Fichero hbm de AsistenciaMedica:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="es.makigas.hibernate.modelo.AsistenciaMedica" table="AsistenciaMedica" >
        <id column="idAsistenciaMedica" name="idAsistenciaMedica" type="integer"/>
        <property name="breveDescripcion" />
        <property name="lugar" />

        <many-to-one name="seguro">
            <column name="id"  />
        </many-to-one>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Una vez que he hecho esto, tengo que probar el programa:

```
package tests;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import es.makigas.hibernate.modelo.AsistenciaMedica;
import es.makigas.hibernate.modelo.Seguro;

public class TestSeguros{
    private static EntityManagerFactory emf=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Persistencia");
    private static EntityManager manager=emf.createEntityManager();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Seguro seguro = new Seguro(311, "12345678Z", "Juan", "Cano", "Morales", 38, 3, LocalDate.of(2015,8,12));

        List<AsistenciaMedica> am=new ArrayList<AsistenciaMedica>();

        am.add(new AsistenciaMedica(311, seguro, "Ir al médico de cabecera por fiebre", "Valencia"));
        //am.add(new AsistenciaMedica(312, seguro, "Operacion de apendicitis", "Castellón"));

        seguro.setAsistenciasmedicas(am);

        manager.getTransaction().begin();

        manager.persist(seguro);

        manager.getTransaction().commit();

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<AsistenciaMedica> a=(List<AsistenciaMedica>) manager.createQuery("FROM AsistenciaMedica").getResultList();
        System.out.println("Incidencias: "+a.size());
        for(AsistenciaMedica as:a){
            System.out.println("Incidencia: "+as.getBreveDescripcion());
        }
        manager.close();
    }
}
```

Y este es el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si os fijais, he omitido una de las instancias AsistenciaMedica, concretamente la que su clave primaria no tiene el mismo valor que la instancia Seguro a la que lo voy a enlazar.

Y esto es lo que pasa cuando no lo omito.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Violación de una restricción de Integridad Referencial: "FKDVN9D4IPYG2WXHRA4HP4N0UM1: PUBLIC.ASISTENCIAMEDICA FOREIGN KEY(IDASISTENCIAMEDICA) REFERENCES PUBLIC.SEGURO(ID) (312)"
Referential integrity constraint violation: "FKDVN9D4IPYG2WXHRA4HP4N0UM1: PUBLIC.ASISTENCIAMEDICA FOREIGN KEY(IDASISTENCIAMEDICA) REFERENCES PUBLIC.SEGURO(ID) (312)"; SQL statement:
insert into AsistenciaMedica (breveDescripcion, lugar, id, idAsistenciaMedica) values (?, ?, ?, ?) [23506-196]
```

Tambien me veo este mensaje de error si lo que hago es omitir a la instancia AsistenciaMedica en la cual su id coincide con el seguro, dejando la que no.

Obviamente este error implica que en la practica tengo una relación 1-1, pues no tengo permitido enlazar si las claves primarias no coinciden.

Esto no me pasa con el ejercicio que tome como base para este. ¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado una solución, aunque es una chapuza practicamente.
Consiste en quitar de los ficheros hbm las relaciones entre las tablas.
El fichero Seguro.hbm.xml quedaria asi:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="es.makigas.hibernate.modelo.Seguro" table="Seguro" >
        <id column="IdSeguro" name="idSeguro" type="integer"/>
        <property name="nif" />
        <property name="nombre" />
        <property name="ape1" />
        <property name="ape2" />
        <property name="edad" />
        <property name="numHijos" />
        <property name="fechaCreacion" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Y AsistenciaSeguro asi:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="es.makigas.hibernate.modelo.AsistenciaMedica" table="AsistenciaMedica" >
        <id column="idAsistenciaMedica" name="idAsistenciaMedica" type="integer"/>
        <property name="breveDescripcion" />
        <property name="lugar" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```